# Viewing a list of Sprints in Azure DevOps

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

In TFS 2019 we could see a list of sprints/iterations down the left-hand side of the screen. This allowed, amongst other things, people to move work between sprints relatively easily by dragging-and-dropping bugs/tasks/stories.

Azure DevOps has replaced this with a drop-down from the Sprints section, to navigate to a different sprint. As there is now no list view, it makes it harder to move work around.

How do we now see a list of sprints/iterations, to assist navigation and to restore the ability to drag-and-drop work into other sprints?

`../_sprints/directory` only shows Teams and the Current sprint, it doesn't show a complete list of past/present/future sprints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to split the iterations into Teams. You would/could create a Product or Project team, and then assign iterations and/or areas to that Team.

From the Sprints page, select your Team from the top-right drop-down, which will then narrow down the list of sprints to select from. Navigating to the Backlog sub-page will then give you the other iterations in that Team on the right-hand side. You can drag-and-drop work items from an iteration into another iteration for the same team from this list. The target iteration will show a green border when hovering the work item over it.

Note: I would add screenshots, but the content is company-sensitive.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT thanks for the reminder. I had to wait 2 days before I could accept it as the answer.